# Firefox : TypeError: window.location.search.includes is not a function

Tags: javascript, firefox

- Go to some site say www.flipkart.com and Open console in firefox
- Type window.location.search.includes('text');
- **TypeError: window.location.search.includes is not a function**
- I Have added the screenshot of my mozilla firefox below.

[image]

EDIT: it works fine on VERSION 41.0.2

Comment: String#includes introduced in firefox version 40

Comment: Ohkk .. just looked at the firefox docs . 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

it has a polyfill included. thanks for your help

Comment: I forgot to add the link. Good to see you found it yourself